# How to always visible horizontal scrollbar of NSTableview in objective c programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, xcode9.1, nsscroller

I have added NSTableview with multiple columns, I want its horizontal scrollbar should always visible, How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create NSScrollview outlet & set in .xib file to superview of NSTableview & used two methods.
- setAutohidesScrollers set NO,
- setScrollerStyle: set NSScrollerStyleLegacy
Set style  NSScrollerStyleLegacy meaning is NSSCrollbars background is not transparent.
This solved my problem, Hope it will help others.