# OS X: How to Always/by default enables/show horizontal scrolling with table view?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Want to always to show horizontal scrolling of NSScrollView with NSTableview, because while user opening window/view he knows that there are some records

Comment: In the attributes inspector in IB uncheck the box beside "automatically hide scroller".

Comment: And set Show scroll bars to Always in the system prefs.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to always visible horizontal scrollbar of NSTableview in objective c programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543845/how-to-always-visible-horizontal-scrollbar-of-nstableview-in-objective-c-program).